# Round-trip pointer casting alignment

Tags: c, pointers, casting, language-lawyer

If I have a pointer `(unsigned long *uptr)` to an array of `(unsigned long)` - or any type with (typically) stricter alignment requirements than `(char)` - and cast:

```
char *bptr = (char *) uptr; /* always works. */
```

Does casting `(bptr)` to `(unsigned long *)` yield the original pointer? I realise that casting *to* a pointer with stricter alignment requirements may not yield a pointer that can be safely derefenced, *in general*. But does the standard guarantee the round-trip of the pointer value in this case?

I can't imagine an implementation of `(char *)` where this wouldn't work as expected, given that it must have at least as many bits in its representation to address bytes. Other answers make the *general* case clear. It just never occurred to me to question whether this was guaranteed.

Comment: Cast to `char*` and back to original type is always valid.

Comment: if your original pointer pointed to an `unsigned long` or allocated memory with size equal or larger than `unsigned long`. Then the standard guarantees alignment. It violates strict aliasing though.

Comment: @Nick char is allowed to alias any type.

Comment: @self, to `char`, but not from `char` to an incompatible type.

Comment: @Nick Sure, but OP is casting back to compatible type.

Comment: @self, `char*` to `unsigned long*` is incompatible. If you refer to the fact that originally the pointer was to `unsigned long`, the compiler might not be aware of this if the casts are done in different contexts.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure what are you trying to say. The debate might be pointless without examples. I said that uint* to char* to uint* is always valid.

Comment: @BrettHale IMO you should more clear on the question and post an example.

Comment: In C++11 you'd be fine on account of C++11 5.2.10/7.

Comment: @self to clarify. Yes, if the cast is `unsigned long` to `char` to `unsigned long`, the resulting pointer is valid (provided the original pointer was properly aligned). What I mean is that if the compiler doesn't know for sure the type of the original pointer, the performance gain of respecting strict aliasing is gone. It was just a "though" in my original comment.

Comment: @self. - I'm not sure what's unclear. I could add a line: `unsigned long *p = (unsigned long *) bptr;` - and ask if `p == uptr` is guaranteed by the standard. I can't really make it any simpler without losing relevance.

Comment: @Nick *if the compiler doesn't know for sure the type of the original pointer* What does that even mean. Does it partially know the type??

Comment: @self Read about strict aliasing optimizations, arguing about semantics is of little use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're fine. C11 6.3.2.3/7 says:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Quoting the same block of text as Kerrek, since the char* pointer must be `correctly aligned for the referenced type` undefined behaviour is avoided and the `result shall compare equal`.

If it was any type other than char, or if you change the value of the char* pointer, then the pointer may no longer be `correctly aligned` and you're back into UB.

You're treading a narrow line, but it's perfectly safe to go there.

Comment: Narrow indeed! It was actually from some (now revised) code where I was too lazy to hang on to both pointers. *Not* a shortcut!